# Adding a custom font to fontconfig

Tags: ssh, fonts, fontconfig

TL;DR: How do i add a custom font (**NarkissNew-Light_MFW**) to fontconfig through SSH?

I am trying to use the wkhtmltopdf utility to convert some HTML with Hebrew in it to PDF. I had some trouble displaying the Hebrew (it appeared as blocks) but after installing **msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.n** the Hebrew displayed correctly (on very specific fonts).
I installed the package in **/usr/share/fonts** and the utility knows how to use at least two of the different fonts there for Hebrew (Arial and the default one).
The problem is i don't know how to install this standalone font.
I tried just placing the files in **/usr/share/fonts** and in the **msttcore** folder inside the fonts folder but it does not work.
I tried placing it in another folder and use fc-cache to redirect to that folder but i received an error of

> "fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol:
>   FcConfigGetSysRoot".

I'm not even sure what files i need since the font has 4 different files (ttf,svg,woff,eot).
Is there maybe a similar package to the msttcore one i can install? or is this just some config parameters and correct command i'm missing?

server information:

CENTOS 6.9 kvm

Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85

Comment: msttcore for centos: http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/ ; but this error can indicate that indeed smth. in the config is broken, and if it persists try to reinstall the fontconfig package

Comment: I already installed msttcore (i said so in the question) and the error is not even what i'm looking to solve... Do you know how to install a singular font to fontconfig? that's my real question..

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Manual_installation, but as I wrote, the error may indicate a corruption in fontconfig files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the problem was the font name I was using in my css file.
I was using "NarkissNew-Light_MFW" (since that was the name of the font files) but the correct name was "NarkissNewMFW". The Hebrew now renders correctly.